# How to check if Stellar's account is valid or exist?

Tags: stellar-sdk, accounts, java-sdk

How to check if account does not exist with the Java SDK? and how to know if a public key is valid?

I found one way to the first question but is not a clean solution

```
Server server = new Server("https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org");
// It will throw HttpResponseException if account does not exist or there was another error.
    try {
        server.accounts().account("GDCI7LNULXXFMM42JAZ4734YU4IVUJEGOHLQRKPXHYJVZGQPEKNN5NNO");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When the account does not exist it accuses an exception but I cannot assure that this is the reason that originated it.

So, exist a pre filter to identify in principle if an account's public key does not have the correct format? (to avoid sending the query to the server)

Answer (score 2):

There is an `ErrorResponse` exception that you can catch. From the `ErrorResponse` you will be able to find the status code of the http request. If the status code is 404 then the account does not exist:

```java
            try {
                 server.accounts().account("GDCI7LNULXXFMM42JAZ4734YU4IVUJEGOHLQRKPXHYJVZGQPEKNN5NNO");
            } catch (ErrorResponse e) {
                if (e.getCode() == 404) {
                    // Account does not exist
                }
                throw e;
            }
```

To check if an account string is a valid public key you can use `KeyPair.fromAccountId()`. If the account string is invalid `KeyPair.fromAccountId()` will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to know if it is a valid address thanks to artificial intelligence:

```
import org.stellar.sdk.KeyPair;
  private boolean isValidPublicKey(String publicKey) {
    try {
        KeyPair.fromAccountId(publicKey);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```